# How to put an image and an a tag on top of each other HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to put an a tag for an href and trying to add it ontop of an image, so that when I click the image it will transmit me to that link. The formatting of the href is off and it will make it smaller than the actual image. My code is below.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <figure class="thumbnail">
                    <a href = "https://www.google.com" style = "position:relative; left: 200px"> 
                    <img src= "img/img-team-5.png" class= "img-responsive" alt= "Image">
                    </a>
                    <figcaption class="caption text-center">




                        <ul class="social-links">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is that unmatched </h3> in your live code? Please include your css or we can't help pinpoint a style discrepancy.

Comment: No, that </h3> is not supposed to be in the code. Sorry/

Answer (score 0):

The image is clickable even the "area of a tag" is smaller than the image. Anyway if you want the a tag with the same size as the image you can try:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Is it what you want?